# Проверить два массива между собой на одинаковые значения

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток**
Помогите пожалуйста с задачей. 
Есть 2 массива, мне нужно проверить их, и удалить в Array1 повторяющиеся значения c массивом Array2

```
 Array1
(
    [0] => 130675
    [1] => 113191
    [2] => 119354
    [3] => 119340
    [4] => 119344
)


Array2
(
    [0] => 119351
    [1] => 130675
    [2] => 119344
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_diff`, `array_intersect` посмотри.

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо.

Comment: незачто........